# How to change default app opened from the terminal in windows 11

Tags: terminal

I tried to run a .sh file in my terminal and accidentally opened it in vscode, now it always opens in vscode even though i want to run it in the terminal itself.

I tried uninstalling vscode so i can get the option to choose again, but that didn't seem to work. I'm too scared to play about with the JSON file incase I mess something up as this is a school project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the default app for the .sh file type. After that, .sh files won't open by vs code.
To do this in windows 11

1. Search For **Default Apps** on start
2. Scroll to the bottom and click **Reset All Default apps**

This will reset all the default apps and you can set the defaults again